# Husband and Wife Watching TV Problem (Probability)

Tags: probability, independence

**The Problem:**

On the basis of past viewing records, an advertising executive has determined that during prime time, husbands are watching TV 40% of the time. It has also been determined that when the husband is watching TV, 60% of the time the wife is also watching. When the wife is not watching TV, 25% of the time the husband is watching TV.

Let us define two events: event H = "husband is watching TV" and event W = "wife is watching TV".

(a) Express three given probabilities by using events ***H*** and ***W***

(b) If the wife is watching TV, what is the **probability** that the husband is not watching?

(c) Are the events ***H*** and ***W*** independent? *Explain* your answer.

---

**My Thoughts:**

(a):

- P(W given H) = 0.6
- P(H) = 0.4
- P (H given 'not W') = 0.25

(b):

- P('not H' given W) = P('not H') x P(W given 'not H')...???

(c): I know that the three equivalent ways to check independence are:

- P(H given W) = P(H)
- P(W given H) = P(W)
- P(H and W) = P(H) and P(W)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**a)** First of all in probability theory event $\{W$ given $H\}$ we write like $\{W|H\}$ and call it condition probability. So you're correct in the a) answers but not write it well. 
$$P\{H\}=0.4 $$
$$P\{W|H\}=0.6 $$
$$P\{H|W^c\}=0.25 $$
where by $W^c$ I denote complement of event $W$.

**b)** Here we must use Bayes theorem or Law of total probability in order to determine that probability with the information we have:

$$P\{H^c|W\}=\frac{P\{H^c,W\} }{P\{W\}}=\frac{0.12}{0.36}=\frac{1}{3}, $$

Then we calculate:
$$P\{W|H \}=0.6,$$
$$P\{W^c|H\}=1-P\{W|H \}=0.4 $$
$$P\{H \}=0.4$$
$$P\{H^c \}=1-P\{H\}=0.6 $$
$$P\{H,W\}=P\{W|H\}P\{H\}=0.24 $$
$$P\{H,W^c\}=P\{H\}-P\{H,W\}=0.16$$
$$0.16=P\{H,W^c\}=P\{W^c\}P\{H|W^c\}=P\{W^c\}\cdot 0.25 \implies P\{W^c\}=\frac{16}{25}=0.64$$
$$P\{W\}=1-0.64=0.36. $$

$$P\{H^c,W^c\}=P\{H^c|W^c\}P\{W^c\}=0.75\cdot 0.64=0.48$$
$$P\{H^c,W\}=P\{H^c\}-P\{H^c,W^c\}=0.12$$

**c)** They are of course dependent, because:
$$0.24=P\{H, W\}\neq P\{H\}P\{W\}=0.4\cdot0.36=0.144$$

Maybe I missed some number or something like that, but the idea is still standing. Good luck!

Comment: Could you explain P{H,Wc}=P{H}−P{H,W}=0.16 to me? I can't seem work my head around it.

Comment: By the law of total probability we have: $0.4=P(H)=P(H, W)+P(H, W^c)$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  Draw a Venn diagram.  Put in each region the percentage of the time it represents.  What percent of the total time are they both watching?  What percent is the husband watching alone?